# MSSQL Error: Multi part identifier Could not bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update a field in a column, but the rows to be updated should be within a range of row numbers.
For example, I want to update endtime for rownumbers between 5 and 50.

So far, I have written this:

```
with updateRows (id, seqid) 
            as ( select id, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by caster) from table1) 
update table1 set modification_date = sysdatetimeoffset() where updateRows.seqid between 5 and 50;
```

When I do this, I get an error on uniqueRows.seqid saying -- the multi part 'updateRows.seqid' identifier couldnnot be bound.

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: In your `UPDATE` statement, `table1` doesn't exist.  You name it `updateRows`.  So replace `table1` with `updateRows`.

Comment: Also, you need to alias your `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Otherwise you can't call the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use you close:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by caster) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) 
update toupdate
    set modification_date = sysdatetimeoffset()
    where seqnum between 5 and 50;
```

Basically there are two changes:

1. The CTE selects all the columns.
2. The `update` directly updates the CTE, so `seqnum` is available for filtering.